# Google Material Icons (font) wont render in mozilla firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, google-material-icons

I am trying to add google material-icons to my WordPress project locally currently on localhost using WAMP. With **CDN**, everything works perfectly but I want a static reference to icons.

**Here is is my directory structure**

```
/
-index.php
-css/
----style.min.css
----MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
----MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
----MaterialIcons-Regular.woff
----MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2
```

**In `style.min.css` I have:**

```
.material-icons{
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';

}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

**When I use icons in body as:**

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE853;</i>
```

The icons render just fine in chrome but not in firefox;
**FireBug** shows this error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource athttp://192.168.0.8/wp/wp-content/themes/thediode/css/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

`192.168.0.8/wp` is the root set in WordPress backend on localhost so that images and other resources are fetched properly and I guess this is the problem.
Any ideas?
will this work when live?

Answer (score 0):

In your URL bar in FF go to about:config.  Find **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** and set it to false.

OR

Might be a file path issue.  Try adding a slash:

```
 url("/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2")
```